# Anthology of science fiction; aliens have humans visit planet for space ship repairs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I think  I've searched the relevant priors so forgive me if this is a duplicate. In the 1980's I read a hard bound anthology of science fiction in a public library. Best guess is that stories were from the 1970s. Red cover, but probably a library binding.

Among the stories was a tale of a large space ship that came to hover over a house, while it made repairs to battle damage. As it lifted away from the planet it became evident that the aliens were humans, and the child watching it was an alien (to us).

Another story concerned people hunting large dinosaur like creatures contained within a force field surrounded jungle.

Comment: Based on another recollected story, of a space ship that only responds to polite commands, I think that this may have been Galactic Adventures published in 1980. Have a copy on order, will advise when confirmed/refuted.